# How to generate an 401 error programmatically in an ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-2.0

As you can see this is a question from a non web developer. I would like to have an ASPX page which, under certain circumstances, can generate a 401 error from code. Ideally it would show the IIS standard page.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Set [Response.StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx) and then - if you need to stop execution - call [Response.End()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx).

Answer (score 61):

```
Response.StatusCode = 401;
Response.End();
```

Comment: I've no idea why this has been voted down - it's pretty much the same as my (voted up) answer, just in code form. Sure, it doesn't have the links which *may* be useful, but it's still a perfectly good answer...

Comment: I totally agree with Jon. Since I can't accept two answers, I accepted Jon's answer and voted up this one. The are a few things I should figure out by myself though but it gave me a head start. Thanks!

Comment: It was probably voted down because it was submitted just after @jon's so it looked like a piggy-back answer (although they were both written simultaneously). Thanks for the upvotes though : )

Comment: The problem this Jon's approach, and this one, is that Forms authentication will see someone trying to return `401`, intercept it, re-write it as `302`. So rather than returning `401`, the user agent is presented `302 Found`.

Answer (score 44):

I think I still prefer:

```
throw new HttpException(401, "Auth Failed")
```

I don't think the `Response.StatusCode` method triggers custom errors defined in the web.config file, e.g.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
     <error statusCode="401" redirect="AuthFailed.htm" />
     <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

Throwing a new exception definitely triggers custom errors.

Also, you might be using an application-wide error logging facility, like [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) or something, and I don't think the `Response.StatusCode` method would be logged there, either.

**Note:** I see now the question said that, ideally, the standard IIS error page should be shown. Obviously, the custom error pages are *not wanted*. I would use the `Response.StatusCode` method in that case.

Comment: Hey that's awesome! Just what I needed to know!

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to just use the following, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.httpexception.aspx).

```
Throw New HttpException(401, "Auth Failed")
```

**Edit** After seeing the other responses setting the status code would be more appropriate.

Comment: I tried this and when I checked the http response in the browser, I got an 500 (Internal Server Error) instead of a 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Also, isn't throwing exception worse in terms of performance?

Comment: I really don't care what is preferred. This method is shorter and easier to remember so I use it.

Answer (score 10):

One additional comment.

If a portion of the page has already been written to the output buffer then it is important that you clear any buffered content or the page may not appear correctly.

This is quite likely in a templated environment.  e.g. Master pages...

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.StatusCode = 401;
Response.End();
```