# ajax calls to controllers. How to indicate success, complete, and error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

If I make an ajax call to a controller.... what needs to happen in the controller so that the ajax call then calls

1) complete:
2) success:
3) error:
4) any other callbacks that exist.

For ex. I have this ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
         url: "/ContactPartial/ContactUs",
         type: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify(data),
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         complete: function () {  },
         success: function () {  },
         error: function () {  }
   });
```

In other words, what can I do inside /ContactPartial/ContactUs to control which of the 3 (complete,success,error) gets called after the controller code executes.

Also, how is this related to related to `return Json(new {some: data});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These three callbacks are related to the status of the Ajax call.  These are called depending on success of the call.  For complete details refer to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

So, if the server responds with a success (200), then both the Success and the Complete handlers would be called.  In the complete handler, you might put some code to dismiss a modal window (regardless of success or error), and in the success function, you might put code to let the user know the call was successful, reload a grid view, etc.  Also, keep in mind that the callback functions don't have to be anonymous functions, they can be defined functions that are shared among several Ajax calls.

EDIT:

If you are wanting to force the server to generate an error, take a look at:

The [HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) class, specifically the [StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx#Y113) property

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217678/how-to-generate-an-401-error-programatically-in-an-asp-net-page) SO post explains more too (generating a 401 error)

Comment: thank you for that explanation. But what determines which code gets return from the server? for example, can i programmatically (in the controller) force an error code to be returned? a success code?

Comment: Only if you can force the server to return an error.  The way it works is you send a request and the server responds with a status code indicated the success/failure/error of the request.

Comment: sorry but I still dont understand how to force the server to return an error. Do u mean add a ModelError to the ModelState then return the model?

Perhaps a code example would go a long way.

Comment: Well, if you gave a url that didn't exist, that would cause an error.  A request with credentials supplied to a website requiring authentication would also cause an error.

Comment: yes but thats all errors cause in the ajax request but doesnt explain how to force an error from inside the controller.

For example: User tries to register for an account. While sending an email verification the SmtpClient throws an exception which is caught by a catch block. How can I immediately break out of the controller and return directly to the error callback (with some error message)? I must be missing something.

Thanks again for your help.