# .net Pop up user/password window

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I'm trying to implement some very basic authentication on my site. I want a user/pass popup window to show if a user tries to access any page (like you can access the site by going to [http://username:password@mysite.com](http://username%3apassword@mysite.com)).

I don't know how to do this, or the best way to do this. The only thing I can think of is maybe using Ajax in my Master Page file? Is there any way to handle this by using a control or something in IIS?

Comment: You want to set up HTTP Basic Authentication in IIS.

Comment: Will this allow different users to have different usernames and passwords? I forgot to mention that in my post - I have a database of username/passwords that I need to reference. I'm assuming no. So is doing this with Ajax the only way to go?

Comment: Doing this with AJAX is completely and utterly useless.  You need to write server-side code.

Comment: Ok. So no AJAX, but I can't do what I need to by using IIS, correct? So I have to write code. What can I use to accomplish this in c#? I've been googling and can't find anything.

Comment: I found this [link](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/) which gave me what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP 401` is a status code that'll trigger the browser's dialog window.

There's another answer that already deals with that, in ASP.NET, here:
[How to generate an 401 error programmatically in an ASP.NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217678/how-to-generate-an-401-error-programatically-in-an-asp-net-page)

You want this:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.StatusCode = 401;
Response.End();
```

Comment: That won't handle authentication at all.

Comment: He didn't ask for authentication, he said he was trying to implement it.  He asked for the password dialog box.