# Throw error of 401 Unauthorized so Web.config shows appropriate page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making an ajax call and if the user is not an admin, i want to throw an error of type 401 - unauthorized and then let the web.config redirect the user to my access denied page:

```
    <customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/InternalError.html"/>
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/AccessDenied.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

As you can see, i have a type 500 - internal server error to handle other errors. But when i run this code:

```
     if (user.Type != AppUser.UserType.SystemAdministrator)
            {
                throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized");
            }
```

web.config thinks a 500 is thrown and shows InternalError.htm instead of AccessDenied.aspx.  How do i tell my ASP.NET application to throw a  401 instead of a 500, so the correct error page will be shown?

This is not MVC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate an 401 error programatically in an ASP.NET page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217678/how-to-generate-an-401-error-programatically-in-an-asp-net-page)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Set the [Response.StatusCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx) instead and it will trigger the redirect.

Alternatively, you can use the below:

```
throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized");
```

Comment: your answer is exactly what i'm doing and i still get the wrong error page. I'm in a static function if that helps

Comment: @BoundForGlory to be fair, you're casting to an int the HttpStatusCode, which *might* act a little different. Also, that was only one option to the answer, I provided a link on how to *set* the `Response.StatusCode` as well, which you should try out. Might be helpful to post the entire method so we can see exactly what else might be going on. It sounds like you might have a `catch` in there somewhere that is overriding the exception.