# Return HTTP Status Code 401 in asp.net server using Visual Studio 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, ashx

I am using visual studio 10 .Net framework 4.0.
I want to send a HTTP response with status code 401. I tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217678/how-to-generate-an-401-error-programmatically-in-an-asp-net-page).

My code is:

```
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
context.Response.End();
```

But I still get status code 200. How do I generate 401 status code?

Comment: I have found the cause of the problem. The problem was that it was being redirected to login page for which the 200 status code was generated.